# How do I change the package name while including native libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an Android project based upon the fantastic code available at http://ikaruga2.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/video-live-wallpaper-part-4/.  Essentially, this app is a live wallpaper that uses FFMpeg to read a video file frame by frame and play it out to screen using GLWallpaperService.

I downloaded the code and was able to get it running successfully on my phone.  I made several changes and then tested again on several devices and all worked fine.  This evening I tried to change the package name from "ffvideolivewallpaper.frankandrobot.com" to "com.nightscapecreations.orionkeysfree".  I did a search and replace in the java, c, and xml files to replace them.  I also modified the c file to replace "Java_ffvideolivewallpaper_frankandrobot_com_NativeCalls" with "Java_com_nightscapecreations_orionkeysfree_NativeCalls".  However, when I run the app on my phone now I receive this error:

```
09-30 12:53:44.911: E/AndroidRuntime(24237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
09-30 12:53:44.911: E/AndroidRuntime(24237):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 12:53:44.911: E/AndroidRuntime(24237): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:   145 could not load needed library '/data/data/ffvideolivewallpaper.frankandrobot.com/lib/libavutil.so' for 'libavcore.so' (load_library[1091]: Library '/data/data/ffvideolivewallpaper.frankandrobot.com/lib/libavutil.so' not found)
09-30 12:53:44.911: E/AndroidRuntime(24237):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
09-30 12:53:44.911: E/AndroidRuntime(24237):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
09-30 12:53:44.911: E/AndroidRuntime(24237):     at com.nightscapecreations.orionkeysfree.NativeCalls.<clinit>(NativeCalls.java:64)
09-30 12:53:44.911: E/AndroidRuntime(24237):     ... 13 more
```

I'm assuming there's a reference to the old package name that I'm missing somewhere, but I can't find anything with Eclipse's file search.  Eclipse is managing the NDK and compiling all the libraries and c code for me.  So far I've tried:

- Doing a clean build
- Restarting Eclipse
- Removing everything in the libs directory and building again

The native calls file that is erroring looks like this:

```
package com.nightscapecreations.orionkeysfree;

public class NativeCalls {
    //ffmpeg
    public static native void initVideo();
    public static native void loadVideo(String fileName); //
    public static native void prepareStorageFrame();
    public static native void getFrame(); //
    public static native void freeConversionStorage();
    public static native void closeVideo();//
    public static native void freeVideo();//
    //opengl
    public static native void initPreOpenGL(); //
    public static native void initOpenGL(); //
    public static native void drawFrame(); //
    public static native void closeOpenGL(); //
    public static native void closePostOpenGL();//
    //wallpaper
    public static native void updateVideoPosition();
    public static native void setSpanVideo(boolean b);
    //getters
    public static native int getVideoHeight();
    public static native int getVideoWidth();
    //setters
    public static native void setWallVideoDimensions(int w,int h);
    public static native void setWallDimensions(int w,int h);
    public static native void setScreenPadding(int w,int h);
    public static native void setVideoMargins(int w,int h);
    public static native void setDrawDimensions(int drawWidth,int drawHeight);
    public static native void setOffsets(int x,int y);
    public static native void setSteps(int xs,int ys);
    public static native void setScreenDimensions(int w, int h);
    public static native void setTextureDimensions(int tx,
                           int ty );
    public static native void setOrientation(boolean b);
    public static native void setPreviewMode(boolean b);
    public static native void setTonality(int t);
    public static native void toggleGetFrame(boolean b);
    //fps
    public static native void setLoopVideo(boolean b);

    static {
    System.loadLibrary("avcore");
    System.loadLibrary("avformat");
    System.loadLibrary("avcodec");
    //System.loadLibrary("avdevice");
    System.loadLibrary("avfilter");
    System.loadLibrary("avutil");
    System.loadLibrary("swscale");
    System.loadLibrary("video");
    }

}
```

How do I resolve this error?  What else needs done when changing the package name?  I'll need to do this many times in the future.

**EDIT:**

It looks like I was looking in the wrong place.  The developer of the original version of the code pointed out that there is a package name passed in when compiling the ffmpeg libraries.  He was nice enough to compile a new version for me with my package name and the wallpaper worked perfectly.  We tried a compile without the package name, but when added to the app it just resulted in:

```
 10-04 08:20:57.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19139): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:   145 could not load needed library 'libavutil.so' for 'libavcore.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libavutil.so' not found)
```

I'm guessing that I'll just need to compile a new version each time I make a new wallpaper.  For those who are trying to do the same, I'd like to point out that the version of ffmpeg used in this project requires version 5 of the ndk; version 9 will not compile it correctly.

I've accepted an existing answer instead of adding my own as it does answer the original intent of my question, even if it didn't resolve this specific issue, and I think it could be helpful to other new developers.

Comment: The chain of .so dependencies is wrong here. As your original error shows, `System.loadLibrary("avutil")` should preceed `avcodec`. Making the `.so` files package aware is a viable alternative, but it a maintenence hell. Unless you put all your `.so` files in one known package (e.g. `ffvideolivewallpaper.frankandrobot.com`) and install them as a separate APK, on which all wallpapers depend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using Eclipse, the proper way to rename the package is to do the following: Right click on project -> Android Tools -> Rename Application Package.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that was even possible.  Extremely useful feature, though.  Tomorrow I will try reverting the changes I made to try it that way.  Will that also update native code?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it will update the native code. I have yet to use the NDK for Android development.

Comment: Eclipse won't mess with the native code, as Alex has pointed out, but his problem isn't with the native code. If he does this combined with his search & replace it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried this and it updated some references, but it left all my java files inside of ffvideolivewallpaper.frankandrobot.com.  I tried running the file, thinking that maybe these could remain here as long as the manifest had been updated, but it resulted in the same error I reported above.  Any further thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I've updated the question with the ultimate resolution to the issue.  Though I think this answer is very helpful in general, especially new developers, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest change would be not to move the NativeCalls class to the new package. This may cause few `import` statements in Java files that use this class, but your C code can be kept unchanged. You can even use it without recompile.

Comment: Alex, I did try this but it did not resolve the problem.  Even with all of my java files in the old package name, the app still errored out due to the new package name in the manifest file.  But thanks for the suggestion.